# Administrator sql queries tool

Tags: sql, thinking-tool

I've been asked to find a reporting solution where a non technical user administrator can search our database for mostly simple information.

Such as how many users are in a specific status (and maybe within a date range) how many uploads have been registered and a number of adhoc queries like this.

I'm an ASP.NET C# programmer and had suggested that we make some queries with drop downs etc that could be added to the administration part of the existing ASP.NET website.

I found Power BI which is full of tools and also jquery datatables for a home grown solution and wondered what other folks like your good self would use.

We use quite a number of enums without description attributes and need to prevent returning client specific information on a number of tables e.g. account holders name, address, email etc whilst returning the count of account holders that have an email address or who are in a specific status.

> sources are MySql db, Azure Sql db, and csv files. Ideally open ended but they are the main ones

Comment: which kind of database? e.g MySql, etc

Comment: @Mawg sources are MySql db, Azure Sql db, and csv files.  Ideally open ended but they are the main ones